# postgres: Grant access to my windows user

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to setup a local database in a windows 10 computer, and grant access to my local windows-user. But when I try to access the database through my node-application I get the following error-message: `error: password authentication failed for user "windowsuser"` using the following db-url: `postgres://localhost:5432/testdb`

I am using the module "pg" to connect to the database, and everything works when I specify a username and password in the URL - but I want to connect using my windows credentials.

I have setup a superuser with the same name as my windowsuser:

```
CREATE ROLE windowsuser LOGIN
    SUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
```

And setup a database windowsuser as owner:

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb
    WITH OWNER = windowsuser
        ENCODING = 'UTF8'
        TABLESPACE = pg_default
        LC_COLLATE = ''
        LC_CTYPE = ''
        CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE testdb TO windowsuser;
```

The windows user has no password, and I want to be able to just login with the current system user. Am I missing something essential here to get proper access?

Comment: Updated the post: using node with pg to connect to the database. The actual username is all lowercase, fixed it in the code examples.

Comment: That is an error in my post :) Its fixed. Its all lowercase in the actual code and error message. But when I replaced the name in the post with an anonymous-name I messed a bit up the casing. Sorry about that.

Comment: why are you leaving the password blank. Create the role windowsuser with password .

Comment: In that case, what would the password be for it to be able to "just work" when using a DB-url without username and password in a node-app? I tried assigning the same password as my local windows user - but that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot simply authenticate without a password. Have a look at the PostgreSQL doc here:
[PostgreSQL: Documentation: 9.4: Authentication Methods](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-methods.html)

You will need to setup "Trust Authentication" instead of "Password Authentication".

> **19.3.2. Password Authentication**
>   "PostgreSQL database passwords are separate from operating system user passwords. The password for each database user is stored in the pg_authid system catalog. Passwords can be managed with the SQL commands CREATE USER and ALTER ROLE, e.g., CREATE USER foo WITH PASSWORD 'secret'. *If no password has been set up for a user, the stored password is null and password authentication will always fail for that user.*"

Is there a specific reason why you are opting to use a Windows system account, as well as no password?